# Is it possible to inject PowerShell window into Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows

I'm looking a way to inject PowerShell window to Windows Taskbar since I often use it to do many tasks by my local PS-modules

Maybe it can be done by some external toolbars? I didn't find any information about it.

The result I look for:

[image]